# Sorts an Array of Objects containing number and name data by displaying sort by number

Tags: java, arrays

There is an array containing number and name data as follows:

```
    Number          Name
    10              Brycen
    6               Devan
    3               Rylan
    1               Gordy
    2               Tim
    4               Curtis
    5               Abe
    9               Melvin
    8               Ansel
    7               Dalton
```

The output should be:

```
    Number          Name
    1               Gordy
    2               Tim
    3               Rylan
    4               Curtis
    5               Abe
    6               Devan
    7               Dalton
    8               Ansel
    9               Melvin
    10              Brycen
```

I've tried it using an Array of Objects and FOR..END-FOR looping. System.out.println(data[i].number); displays output in order but for System.out.println(data[i].name); display the original state.

```
class StudentList { //DaftarSiswa
    public int number;
    public String name;
    
    public StudentList(int number, String name) {
        this.number = number;
        this.name   = name;
    }
}

class OrderNumber { //NomorUrut
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StudentList[] data = new StudentList[10];
        data[0] = new StudentList(10, "Brycen");
        data[1] = new StudentList( 6, "Devan");
        data[2] = new StudentList( 3, "Rylan");
        data[3] = new StudentList( 1, "Gordy");
        data[4] = new StudentList( 2, "Tim");
        data[5] = new StudentList( 4, "Curtis");
        data[6] = new StudentList( 5, "Abe");
        data[7] = new StudentList( 9, "Melvin");
        data[8] = new StudentList( 8, "Ansel");
        data[9] = new StudentList( 7, "Dalton");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < data.length; j++) {
                int tmp = 0;
                if (data[i].number > data[j].number) {
                    tmp            = data[i].number;
                    data[i].number = data[j].number;
                    data[j].number = tmp;
                }
            }
            
            System.out.println(data[i].name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why have you called this class `StudentList`? Its instances represent single students, don't they?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're just swapping the numbers. You need to swap the entire object.:

```
if (data[i].number > data[j].number) {
    Student tmp = data[i];
    data[i] = data[j];
    data[j] = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make your `Student` (renamed from `StudentList`) class to implement [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface in order to sort your array using [Arrays.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html) method. In this case you must add to Student class implementation of [compareTo](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) method.

```
class Student implements Comparable<Student> { //DaftarSiswa
    public int number;
    public String name;

    public Student(int number, String name) {
        this.number = number;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student o) {
        return this.number - o.number;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student {number=" + number + ", name='" + name +"'}\n";
    }
}

public class Test { //NomorUrut
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student[] data = new Student[10];
        data[0] = new Student(10, "Brycen");
        data[1] = new Student(6, "Devan");
        data[2] = new Student(3, "Rylan");
        data[3] = new Student(1, "Gordy");
        data[4] = new Student(2, "Tim");
        data[5] = new Student(4, "Curtis");
        data[6] = new Student(5, "Abe");
        data[7] = new Student(9, "Melvin");
        data[8] = new Student(8, "Ansel");
        data[9] = new Student(7, "Dalton");

        Arrays.sort(data);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java Streams for that, which a more elegant than loops, in my opinion.

Assuming `StudentList` class normally would have getters (and setters), you could it do this way:

```
public class OrderNumber { //NomorUrut
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StudentList[] data = new StudentList[10];
        data[0] = new StudentList(10, "Brycen");
        data[1] = new StudentList( 6, "Devan");
        data[2] = new StudentList( 3, "Rylan");
        data[3] = new StudentList( 1, "Gordy");
        data[4] = new StudentList( 2, "Tim");
        data[5] = new StudentList( 4, "Curtis");
        data[6] = new StudentList( 5, "Abe");
        data[7] = new StudentList( 9, "Melvin");
        data[8] = new StudentList( 8, "Ansel");
        data[9] = new StudentList( 7, "Dalton");

        Arrays.stream(data) // Start stream
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(StudentList::getNumber)) // Sort by Number
                .forEach(student -> System.out.println(student.getName())); // Output (like you shown in code) 
    }
}
```

If you also want to have an list or array sorted in that order you could `collect` it.

```
// get sorted list of students
var students = Arrays.stream(data) // Start stream
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(StudentList::getNumber)) // Sort by Number
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // collect to list

// if you really want an array
var studentsArray = students.toArray(new StudentList[students.size()]);
```

Comment: Don’t initialize the array with a size. Use `students.toArray(new StudentList[0])` Pre-sizing the array is a bad habit from early Java times.

Comment: It would be easier and fasterjust to sort data in your second example than to do the stream sort